# Discord bot node.js currency system guide bot error

Tags: discord

So I was making a discord bot and put in all the code for the discord currency system, when it failed to start I even copied and pasted the resulting code and it still failed, I put in everything so what is going wrong? The error is:

```
 Error: Cannot find module
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)←[39m
←[90m    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: []
}
```

I don't know what to do at this point, google has been no help and I dont know what its even referring to.

Comment: While we do support Discord questions, this seems more suited for StackOverflow

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs on [so] | Edit: This is a duplicate of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758612/i-am-having-an-error-in-running-a-node-js-file)

Comment: Regardless of whether or not it's a duplicate, this question won't be accepted on Stack Overflow as written because it is missing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a `require()` statement to import a dependency, or have forgotten to run `npm install` to install a dependency.

When you post this on StackOverflow, please include the snippet of code that is causing this error.

---

Update: *Don't* post it to StackOverflow. You'll likely be marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65758612/3505377).

A quick Google search for `at node:internal/main/run_main_module MODULE_NOT_FOUND` found that.